# Appium iOS driver not passing safariAllowPopups settings

Tags: ios, iphone, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm setting the `safariAllowPopups` to `true` in the device desired capabilities. But for some reason it seems that Appium is not passing that setting to the device (`window.open` is not working, and when checking the `settings` page, Safari is still set with the popup blocker `on`)

I'm using Appium 1.3.6 and testing on iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1 and 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this might be fixed in the upcoming 1.4 release: https://github.com/appium/appium/pull/4928.